# Will charges rearrange inside a conductor, or not?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, conductors

I'm confused about how conductors work.

So, imagine we have a spherical conductor, charged with a certain potential, $V$, that must remain constant.
Now, this sphere has a cavity inside, where we put a certain charge $q_1$.
I guess, since the electric field must be $0$ inside the conductor, charges will rearrange in such a way that they cancel the field produced by the cavity ($q_1$), is this correct?
If it is, then, imagine we put another charge, $q_2$, outside the sphere. Will charges rearange to cancel the field produced by this charge? Will the total charge, $Q$ remain constant? Would there be a (non-zero) charge density $\rho$ inside the conductor?

So confusing!

Comment: By definition (in the static case), a conductor enforces the condition that $\vec{E} = 0$ in the bulk of the conductor. Why? Because any non-zero field would produce a force on the "free" electrons contained in the conductor, causing the electrons accelerate and rearrange into regions of higher and lower charge density. This will continue until the electrons have rearranged in such a way that they are no longer accelerating (by assumption, since we are in the static case), i.e. there is no force, i.e. there is no electric field.

Comment: An interesting point of fact is that all of this rearrangement has to happen at the boundary (surface) of the conducting body. The interior of a conductor in the static case is electrically neutral. This follows from Gauss's law and the fact that the field is zero in the bulk of the conductor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the charges rearrange to that the total field inside the conductor is zero---that is, the sum of the fields due to $q_1$ and $q_2$ will vanish. No, the **total** amount of charge inside the conductor does not change, but it might happen that there's more positive charge here, more negative charge there, and so on, but always in a way that keeps the total amount of charge constant.

Comment: Thanks! That rises another question then. Knowing $\nabla\cdot\vec{E}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon _0}$, then $\rho$ should be $0$ (because $\vec{E}=0$). But it's not, since you are saying that there is a distribution inside the sphere. Isn't that weird?

Comment: @Ruba18 That is a very good point. I'm not sure of the answer right now. I suggest you post it as a new question so more people can have a look at it (reference this question in the new post if you want to)

Comment: @Ruba18 you should link the new question in the comments. But, briefly, you can't apply Gauss's law because the field is not continuous (let alone differentiable) at the surface of an ideal conducting body.