# If $\vec{E}=0$ inside a conductor, then there's no charge distribution?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, conductors

I got this answer to my last post,
[See answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/798300).
That raises another question, then. Knowing $\nabla\cdot\vec{E}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon _0}$, then $\rho$ should be $0$ (because $\vec{E}=0$). But it's not, since we agreed there is a distribution inside the sphere. Isn't that weird?

Maybe the only charge distribution lies on the surface; that's why the charge distribution is $0$ in the conductor idk...

Comment: A conductor in an electrostatics problem will not have charges on the insides. There will instead be a complicated charge distribution on the surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

$E=0\implies\rho=0$ is correct and any net charge resides on the surface. Hence we can say $\rho=0$ inside the conductor with no contradiction. Note $E\neq0$ can be true just outside of the surface. Look in Chapter 2 of Griffths Electrodynamics 4th edition, page 98 for more questions related to this topic. Gausses law is indeed the full explanation for the first assertion.

Answer (score 0):

The charge distribution of a conductor is concentrated on its surface. Two simple examples:

1. A conductor filling the half space $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3|z\le 0\}$ with its surface being the whole $x$-$y$ plane. The charge distribution is then given by $\rho(x,y,z)= \sigma \delta(z)$, where $\sigma$ is the surface charge density. In this case, $\vec{E}(x,y,z)= (\sigma/\varepsilon_0)\Theta(z) \vec{e}_z$ and indeed, $$\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{E} = (\sigma/\varepsilon_0) \frac{\partial \Theta(z)}{\partial z}=(\sigma/\varepsilon_0) \delta(z).$$
2. A conducting ball centered at the origin with radius $R$ carrying a total charge $Q$ , $B_R=\{(r,\theta,\varphi)|0\le r\le R, \;0\le \theta \le \pi, \; 0\le \varphi\lt 2\pi\}$ in spherical coordinates. The charge is concentrated on the surface $\partial B_R=\{(r,\theta,\varphi)|r=R, \; 0\le \theta \le \pi, \; 0\le \varphi \lt 2\pi\}$ with surface charge density $\sigma=Q/(4\pi R^2)$ and (space) charge density $\rho(r,\theta,\varphi)=\sigma \delta(r-R)$. The divergence of the electric field $$\vec{E}(r,\theta,\varphi)=\frac{Q \Theta(r-R)}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2} \vec{e}_r$$ is indeed given by $$\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{E}(r,\theta,\varphi) =\frac{Q}{4\pi \varepsilon_0 r^2}\frac{\partial \Theta(r-R)}{\partial r}= \frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 R^2}\delta(r-R)=(\sigma/\epsilon_0)\delta(r-R).$$

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful with surface charges. Inside a conductor, if no high very high frequency is involved, the electric field and the net charge distributions are zero.

This is because of the small value of the resistivity $\sigma$ (relating the electric field $\mathbf{e}$ and the current density $\mathbf{j}$, $\mathbf{e} = \sigma \mathbf{j}$) and dielectric constant $\varepsilon$. Using the Gauss' law for the dielectric field $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{d} = \rho$, the continuity equation for the electric charge becomes
\begin{equation}
  \partial_t \rho = \nabla \cdot \mathbf{j} = \dfrac{1}{\sigma} \nabla \cdot \mathbf{e} = \dfrac{1}{\sigma \varepsilon} \rho \ .
\end{equation}
The solution of this equations reads
\begin{equation}
  \rho(\mathbf{r}, t) = \rho_0(\mathbf{r}) e^{-\frac{t}{\sigma \varepsilon}} \ ,
\end{equation}
i.e. an initial charge distribution $\rho_0(\mathbf{r})$ rapidly vanishes, since the time constant for a conductor is of the order $\tau = \sigma \varepsilon \sim 1.78 \cdot 10^{-8} \Omega m \, \cdot 8.85 \cdot 10^{-12} F \, m^{-1} \sim 10^{-19} s$.

For an example involving the role of surface charge distributions in conductors and dielectrics, have a look at the examples at the end of this answer
[Interpretation of Gauss law for displacement field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/798254/interpretation-of-gauss-law-for-displacement-field/798257#798257)